# How do I lease an individual blob in an Azure storage container using BlobLeaseClient?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

The documentation around this seems very confusing. It seems that this was possible using the now deprecated `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob` nuget package using the [`CloudBlobContainer.AcquireLease`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.acquirelease?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) method.

The updated `BlobLeaseClient` has an [`Acquire()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobleaseclient.acquire?view=azure-dotnet) method which states:

> The Acquire(TimeSpan, RequestConditions, CancellationToken) operation
> acquires a lease on the **blob** or container.

But it's not clear how this is supposed to be used. I can't find any examples of this, though I have found examples of the deprecated packages.

At the moment I have this:

```cs
//injected using AddBlobServiceClient, etc. Uses DefaultAzureCredential
private BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient;

blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("containerName");



BlobLeaseClient blc = blobContainerClient.GetBlobLeaseClient();

//throws exception here
BlobLease bl = await blc.AcquireAsync(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
```

but when I run this I just get:

```
The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
RequestId:<guid>
Time:2020-09-30T10:28:47.8781946Z
Status: 400 (The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.)
ErrorCode: InvalidHeaderValue

Headers:
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: <guid>
x-ms-client-request-id: <guid>
x-ms-version: 2019-12-12
x-ms-error-code: InvalidHeaderValue
Date: Wed, 30 Sep 2020 10:28:47 GMT
Content-Length: 328
Content-Type: application/xml
```

I'm also not sure this is going to lease the bob as at no point have I specified what blob I want to lease.

Does anyone know how to use the BlobLeaseClient correctly for this situration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to get a reference to a blob:

```cs
blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("containerName");
var blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient("my.blob");
```

then create a lease client and acquire a lease:

```
var blc = blobClient.GetBlobLeaseClient();
var bl = await blc.AcquireAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
```

Comment: Great thanks. I've tried quite a few permutations of this flow, all of which looked like they should work but didn't. Seems somewhat particular about how exactly you use these objects.

Comment: So an important gotcha it seems for this is that you must [specify a time period between 15-60 seconds or else you get an error](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/15555#issuecomment-702299375). Which is documented but I have no idea why this [helper class lets you specify other time periods if that's a limiting factor](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/15555#issuecomment-702587939).

Comment: Does it cause issues for you? You can lock it for say 60 seconds and release it once your done, which could be in less than 10 seconds.

Comment: It does make you wonder why these restrictions are there in the first place.

Comment: I can work around it. It's just frustrating that the message was so opaque. Just wanted to add the comment in case anyone else had this issue and needed this info.